# Regex only with starting match

Tags: regex, perl

I am familliar with capturing multiple words with a definite match in perl, eg:

```
$string="dasd 341312 ddas 42 fsd 5345";
@numbers=$string=~/(\d+)/g;
```

This returns an array of numbers in my string.

I have data in this form:

```
random
text
START=somenumber
lines
of
text
here
START=someothernumber
other
text
here
START=thirdnumber
more
text
...
```

How can I capture  to array all data blocks beginning with `START=` and going on (multiline) until the next `START=` (without it).

so eg:

```
$array[1] = "    START=someothernumber
             other
             text
             here"
```

Comment: Sometimes, using `split` is easier.

Comment: can this be still done with a regex?

Comment: if i do @array=$data=~/(START=.*?)START=/gs;, i lose the second "START=", and the regex then skips the second block (and fourth, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my @array = $data =~ /(START=.+?)(?=START=|\z)/gs;
print Dumper \@array;

__DATA__
random
text
START=somenumber
lines
of
text
here
START=someothernumber
other
text
here
START=thirdnumber
more
text
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'START=somenumber
lines
of
text
here
',
          'START=someothernumber
other
text
here
',
          'START=thirdnumber
more
text
'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of doing this. Switch on multiline and global replace and then remember that you have to handle the new lines ( this is the key to unwinding this ). This will solve your issue:

`while ($string =~ /^.*?START=([\w\s\n]*$)/mg) {
    print $1,"\n";
}`